# Jmeter Xpath and Regular expression

Tags: java, regex, xpath, jmeter

I need to extract jsessionid value only 8969424C7F388504711149044AB03FE9 from the below code

```
<input type="hidden" name="execution" value="e1s1" />
 <input type="hidden" name="_eventId" value="submit" />
 <a id="forgotP" href='forgotPassword?service=https%3A%2F%2Fbg-cn-host%3A8443%2Fcloudsolutions%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check%3Bjsessionid%3D8969424C7F388504711149044AB03FE9'>Forgot password?</a>
 <input class="btn-submit" name="submit" value="Log In
```

I tried following options but no luck

```
//*[starts-with(@href,'forgotPassword')]/substring-after(@href, 'jsessionid%3D')
```

substring-after(/@href, 'jsessionid%3D')

```
//*[@id='forgotP']/contains(substring-after(., 'jsessionid%3D'))

name="(.+)"\stype="hidden"value="(.+)"
```

Need both Xpath and Regular expression

Comment: I tried this    id="forgotP"\shref="(.3D+?)"\s*

Answer (score 1):

Correct XPath Expression would be:

```
substring-after(//a[starts-with(@href,'forgot')]/@href,'jsessionid%3D')
```

If your response is not XML/XHTML-compliant make sure that "Use Tidy (tolerant parser)" box is checked

You can test XPath Expressions against response data using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

[image: Xpath Extractor]

However I believe you can do it a lot easier. Given JSESSIONID is just a cookie, it should be perfectly handled by the [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), besides XPath Extractor is known to be resource intensive and it is recommended to avoid using it where possible.

1. Add the following line to *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
2. Restart JMeter
3. Add HTTP Cookie Manager to your Test Plan
4. Wherever you need JSESSIONID value you can use `${COOKIE_JSESSIONID}` variable

For more information see [Using the HTTP Cookie Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) guide.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex,

```
3Bjsessionid\%3D(\w+)'>Forgot password
```

or

```
3Bjsessionid\%3D([0-9A-Z]+)'>Forgot password
```

I am not giving JMeter regex snapshot assuming you know Regex extractor in JMeter. For Xpath I think your Xpath query is correct.